# Low Dimensional Spin Manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spin-geometry, orbifolds

I am looking for examples of 2- and 3-dimensional flat spin manifolds with Euclidean and Lorentzian  signatures, which admit parallel spinors and the dimension of the space of the parallel spinors is equal to 1. At the moment I have examples only for the Lorentzian case:$\mathbb{R}^{1,1}_{*}/(Z_{2})$ (for dimension 2) and $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}_{*}/(Z_{2}) \times \mathbb{R}$ (for dimension 3). Here $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}_{*}$ means $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and the generator of $Z_2$ acts as $x  \mapsto (-x)$.  However, I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Your both examples are correct.